# Which languages have been implemented on the Common Language Runtime?

Tags: .net, clr

Does anyone know of a comprehensive list of languages that target the .NET Common Language Runtime?

I'm interested specifically in Windows implementations but if there is a list that includes CLI languages on other platforms (Mono, etc) then that's helpful, too. I just can't seem to uncover this information in Google.

Comment: I think most of the answers in the links below are of the sort 'once upon a time 3 years ago, someone ported this language to .Net and posted a web link that now no longer works'.  Depending on how pragmatic you need to be (e.g. looking for languages that are alive & well & have any support) I expect the list is much shorter.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Brian in the comment above, the degrees to which languages are/were implemented full and/or are still being maintained varies drastically.

There's a complete list maintained as a wiki by Brian Ritchie,
https://bitbucket.org/brianritchie/wiki/wiki/.NET%20Languages

Comment: Yeah, I know where THAT link goes ;-) I just couldn't find the right keywords. Sometimes Google is like that. You can find almost anything if you know what is in the results before you search for them ;-)

Comment: <sheepish>Thanks for taking my cheap overzealousness so warmly :)</sheepish>

Answer (score 0):

What about VB.net comapred to its previous incarnation ? That worked out well and was seemless...

Answer (score 0):

Progress OpenEdge uses the CLR .net bridge.